# tinyMCE HTMLField not showing the results properly in Django

Tags: html, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

here is what i'm doing on **template**.

```
<p class="card-text"> 
{{ profile.about}}    
</p>
<h5>skills:</h5>
<p class="card-text">{{ profile.skills }}</p>
</div>
```

here's what i'm returning from **views.py**

```
def about(request):
     profiles = models.profiles.objects.all()
     return render(request,'main/about.html',{'profiles':profiles})
```

here's what i've done in models.py

```
#from tinymce.models import HTMLField
about = HTMLField()
```

**glance at a form:**
[IMAGE OF A FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIjhB.png)

**This is what i'm getting when i display it.**
It doesn't show rich text, it shows html tags instead.

[the result of tinyMCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ2BU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a form not the profile object.

`forms.py`

```py
    class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            fields = ['skills']
            model = Profile  # Model names should be PascalCase
```

`views.py`

```py
    def about(request, profile_id):
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile.objects.all(), pk=profile_id)
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
        return render(
            request,
            'main/about.html',
            {'profile': profile, 'form': form}
        )
```

You also need to use the media files for the form

`main/about.html`

```
...
{{ form.media }}
...
```